# Remote Scripting in Opera handheld widget

Tags: javascript, widget, opera

I have to do a widget that calls functions from a remote javascript file, my problem is that i dont know how configure that in config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question entirely, but perhaps this helps?

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-widgets-security-model/#enablenetwork